# How to enhance the performance of a Java application that makes many calls to the database?

Tags: java, performance

As per my understanding the execution of java programs is pretty fast, things that slow down an application are mainly Network and IO operations.

For example, if I have a for loop running 10000 times which opens a file, processes some data and saves the data back into the file. **If at all the application is slow, it not because of the loop executing 10000 times but because of the file opening and closing within the loop.**

I have an MVC application where before I view a page I go through a Controller which in turn calls Services, which finally calls some DAO methods.

***The problem is that there are so many queries being fired before the page loads and hence the page load time is 2 mins, which is pathetic.***

Since the service calls various DAO methods and each DAO method uses a different connection object, I thought of doing this: **"Create only one DAO method that the Service would call and this DAO method would fire all queries on one Connection object."**

*So this would save the time of connecting and disconnecting to the database.*

But, the connection object in my application is coming from a connection pool. And most connection pools don't close connections they just send them back to the connection pools. So my above solution would not have any effect as anyways there is no opening and closing of connections.

How can I enhance the performance of my application?

Comment: I would try to reduce the count of queries beeing fired. You usually don't need so much at once. Look for data you already get by another query or try to combine queries in some way. If nothing works out for you, you should make it async (like AJAX does)

Comment: @Jan : I tried to reduce the queries but the requirement says that I need so much data, and each query is completely different from another. And the AJAX call itself takes 1min 47 secs. The time of execution on server is too much what should I do ?

Comment: Could you split it into more AJAX calls? That produces overhead but if you don't need everything at once can display results that are already available. Other answers are already mentioned: Profiler and performance optimization or Caching. Sadly: In some cases the requirements are just wrong / not realistic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions :

- Scale your database. Perhaps the database itself is just slow.
- Use 'second level caching' or application session caching to
  potentially speed things up and reduce the need to query the
  database.
- Change your queries, application or schemas to reduce the number of
  calls made.

Comment: I am not allowed to touch the schema

Comment: Are you using any sort of caching? If you're using Hibernate etc. you can just enable second level caching. If your application makes the same query twice, the second time it won't reach the database.

Comment: Nope. Using Pure JDBC.

Comment: Ok. If you could somehow 'intercept' calls to your DAO methods you could :
Check to see if this call has already been made, if it has, return it from 'somewhere else', otherwise call the database, put the result 'somewhere else' and then return it. To do this you would use AOP and EHCache.
Are you using Spring?

Comment: Actually by the sound of your response to Jan above, caching will probably not help. You just need to make your database 'better'. What is your database technology? Can you cluster it?

Comment: I am using Oracle as my database. I am not a database guy so I don't understand this clustering stuff. But please share with me any info about it I can ask my colleges to solve it for me.

Comment: I think you just need to get your DBA guys to make the database faster.
If it's an Oracle database you might consider something like RAC. Though I'm also not a DBA.

Comment: Turns out Query optimization was the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should accurately determine where the time is spent using tools like Profiler.

Once the root cause is known you can see if the operations can be optimized, i.e remove unnecessary steps. If not then you can see if the result of the operations can be cached and reused.

Without accurate understanding of processing that is taking time, it will be difficult to make any reasonable optimization.

Comment: I don't know this profiler thing. But I use custom DateDifference methods around the time consuming methods to check their performance. The time spent on Server is 1 min 50 sec

Comment: Profiler can tell you more details like the methods that are called most often, the average time spent in methods etc. Sometimes profiling can reveal interesting things which are causing performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you reuse connection objects from the pool, this means that the connection/disconnection does not create any performance problem.

I agree with Ashwinee K Jha that a Profiler would give you some clear information of what you could optimize.

Meanwhile some other ideas/suggestions:

1. Could you maintain some cache of answers? I guess that not all of the 10,000 queries are distinct!
2. Try tuning the number of Connection objects in the Pool. There should be an optimal number.
3. Is your query execution already multi-threaded? I guess it is, so try tuning the number of threads. Generally, the number of cores is a good number of threads BUT, in the case of I/Os a much larger number is optimal (the big cost is the I/Os, not the CPU)

Answer (score 0):

You can use The [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) which use connection pool, calling database IO is costly, but mostly **db connection openning and closing** take good chunk of time.
You can also increase the maxIdle time (The maximum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool)
Also you can look into **in memory data grid** eg [hazelcast](http://hazelcast.com/) etc